Distort frequency spectrum in python signal
I have a signal with clear frequency peaks, I want to distort the signal that the frequency peaks are not distinct but much broader (see picture).
I'm working with python and don't have any idea how this can be done. I want to generate sound files in the end.


MIAWANG has the mathematical answer: multiply by a kernel in the time domain. But the slight problem is the suggestion of a Gaussian kernel. This is very localized in the time domain. It achieves the desired effect by discarding almost all sound not near the peak of the Gaussian kernel.
Using a sinc (sin x/x) kernel instead will achieve a similar smoothing in the frequency domain, but less of a concentration in time. Using multiple kernels with peaks at different times, averaging the results, is even more effective.


figure (1) shows the common spectrum pattern of audio signals.
to obtain the spectrum curve shown in figure (2) , we can apply the convolution to the spectrum in frequency domain using the Gaussian kernal.
please refer to https://www.quora.com/Why-is-convolution-in-time-domain-equivalent-to-frequency-multiplication .

The idea here is correct, but the quora link is slightly misleading. It talks about convolution in the time domain, while your idea hinges on convolution in the frequency domain. Luckily, this works both ways. You can indeed multiply in the time domain.
